# Kendo UI duplicated grid inside Kendo UI window with Knockout JS bindings

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kendo-ui

I'm working with Kendo UI and Knockout JS libraries and have a strange problem.
I'm trying to display kendo grid within kendo window, but the rows inside the grid get duplicated.
Here's a piece of code:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var clients = { FilteredClients: [{ ClientName: '1', ClientCode: 'Value 1' }, { ClientName: '2', ClientCode: 'Value 2'}], Header: 'TEST' };
        var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(clients);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

        var showClientLookupWindow = function () {

            var window = $("#clientLookupWindow").data("kendoWindow");
            window.center();
            window.open();
        }

        $('#btnClientLookup').bind('click', showClientLookupWindow);
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a id="btnClientLookup" href="#" class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-search"><span
            class="k-icon k-search"></span>Client Lookup</a>

    <span data-bind="text: Header"></span>
    <div id="clientLookupWindow" data-bind="kendoWindow: { isOpen: false, visible: false, width: '600px', height: '230px', modal: true, resizable: false, title: 'Client Lookup'}">
        <div id="gridClients" data-bind="kendoGrid: { data: FilteredClients, columns: [ { field: 'ClientName', title : 'Client Name' }, { field: 'ClientCode', title: 'Client Code' } ], scrollable: false, sortable: true, pageable: false }">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="gridClientsOutside" data-bind="kendoGrid: { data: FilteredClients, columns: [ { field: 'ClientName', title : 'Client Name' }, { field: 'ClientCode', title: 'Client Code' } ], scrollable: false, sortable: true, pageable: false }">
    </div>
</div>
```

Running it in the browser, we see that there are 2 rows in gridClientsOutside, but after clicking btnClientLookup, the window pops up with the gridClients, which consists of 4 rows.
Did anyone encounter this issue or have a workaround for this?

Thanks in advance,
Ihor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a quick glance, it looks like the bindings inside the `kendoWindow` section are getting bound twice, which is causing the issue.

There bindings can run in an async mode and that is probably how `kendoWindow` should be set in the knockout-kendo library.

For the moment, you can do this:

```
<div id="clientLookupWindow" data-bind="kendoWindow: { async: true, isOpen: false, visible: false, width: '600px', height: '230px', modal: true, resizable: false, title: 'Client Lookup'}">
```

This adds `async: true` in the `kendoWindow` binding options.  Otherwise, you could do `ko.bindingHandlers.kendoWindow.options.async = true;` to set it globally, before calling applyBindings.

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/2MexC/

Comment: I made `kendoWindow` async by default in the library now, if you want to grab the latest version.